# Auto close window while using Chrome by window.open in jsp page

Tags: java, javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am using this code inside a jsp page to get some information from another jsp :

Error: the resultant jsp page is just blinking and closed automatically.

```
<script>
var newWindow=window.open("test.jsp");
opener.self();
self.close();
</script>
```

Please tell me how to solve this problem

Thanks in advance,

raj

Comment: You want to close `newWindow`?

Comment: Hi @GuillaumePolet my requirement is when i click on a button say 'test'in a page, new window should be opened to display the results 
of steps performed in "test.jsp".

Problem: that window is just blinking and closing automatically.
In other browsers its working fine

Comment: I am confused by your code. As I understand JS: `var newWindow=window.open("test.jsp");`opens a new windows pointing to test.jsp.  I don't know what does `opener.self();`. And `self.close();` close the current window

Comment: Hi @GuillaumePolet if i dont use that line, a new extra window is being opened. so i added that line so that only the self window ha to be opened

Comment: Now you got me completely lost. _my requirement is when i click on a button say 'test'in a page, **new window should be opened** to display the results of steps performed in "test.jsp"_ What do you mean by _the self window has to be opened_ ? Sorry, but what you are saying does not make any sense to me. Maybe somebody else understands better what you mean.

Comment: Paste your 'test.jsp' page code. (javascript part)

Comment: also paste this page's code from where you are calling this function. (the button)..

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it's this simple or not, but your last two lines of code are confusing and I'm not sure why they're there.  But there might be something I'm missing.  Either way, try removing them:

```
<script>
var newWindow = window.open("test.jsp");
</script>
```

Comment: Hi @LukeGT if i dont use that lines, a new extra window is being opened. so i added those lines

Comment: If you don't want a new window to be opened, then why are you using window.open()?  Because that's exactly what it does.  Are you trying to just navigate to another page?  Could you edit your question and be clearer about your problem?

Comment: i want a new window, my problem is i am getting third window, but expected is two windows.one is home page and other is resultant.
So i have added those extra lines.

Comment: Well there lies the problem, why are you getting two windows for a single call of window.open()?  Is there perhaps some Javascript within 'test.jsp' that opens another window?  Is your code running twice for a single mouse click?

Comment: @rajasti277 is that javascript in the page test.jsp? If yes, then that would create an infinite loop (which is probably prevented by the browsers)

Comment: @GuillaumePolet the code above is not in test.jsp, there is call to test.jsp from a jsp where the above code lies.